# Trying to create a function that returns int pointer, got a build error instead

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, gcc

I'm trying to create a function that returns an int pointer value with Eclipse kepler IDE and I got this error while trying to build it.

```
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
#error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
^
```

How do I enable the "the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options." ?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int* maxVal (int num[], int numSize)
{
    int *max;
    max = &num[0];
    for (int i=0; i<numSize; i++){
        if (num[i] >= *max)
            max = &num[i];
    }
    return max;
}
int main() {
    int num[] = {23, 45, 67, 8};
    cout << maxVal(num, sizeof(num));
    return 0;
}
```

I really have no idea what's wrong/ Is there a syntax error instead? The IDE doesn't tell so :/

Thanks in advance for your feedback. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You simply pass these options to your compiler call? You'll need to find this in the project options of your IDE. For Eclipse it's under `C++ Build Options -> Compiler -> Misc` IIRC.

Comment: Just add -std=c++11 to the command line to make it happy trivially.  I don't know what makes it think you need it

Comment: Your code is not using any C++11 features. Remove line `#include <array>` and try to run again.